# Is it possible to define multiple function bodies or if conditions depending on an individual function argument type?

Tags: typescript

As I'm researching for a solution to my question, I want to highlight, that an answer to my question should not assume that a native javascript type is used. For those cases a simple `instanceof type === <native type, e.g. string | number | ...>` might be solution to my problem. In the following you see an example of what am I want to use.

```
foo(fruits: Fruits.ApiResponse[] | Fruits.ClassInstances[]) {
 if (Fruits.ApiResponse[])
   ...
 if (Fruits.ClassInstances[])
   ...
}
```

alternatively a solution might also be structured as follows:

When calling the same function for multiple types it should react on the input data type.

```
foo(fruits: Fruits.ApiResponse[]) {
  // do things with Fruits.ApiResponse[]
}
foo(fruits: Fruits.ClassInstances[]) {
  // do things with Fruits.ClassInstances[]
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something similiar to [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAIYD6ADmQE5mYBciAzlLYUQJTNgiYAjbLQCwAKFCRYCFOiy4CxctToNe-IbR6t2ncZOjwkqDDnydlNek0R9BwxAB8dHYtrauiT2xocBvcUQgxBhgEigATypsOGBESisGRABeVMQAcjtNdK5EWlwQWiR0gAlsABtyuEQAdThacuR0gG5A4NDwqJi4hNVMFLT0j04cvIKixABmVrFgxHxaOAB3W2wVgFFaRdoSAAMAVTBsAA9o6Gxkea7drhmAX3FxCAQ2eJTZUwULUoqq2vrGjlmogAPQgnz2URiZ5gV4Cd4meTmJQARgADGjbqDwcNiEA)?

Comment: For me the function overloads might be a solution, but those examples (that I've seen so far) just do support one function body and not multiple to distinguish between different types or am I getting it wrong?

And the provided example in the link just uses the native JS types, which do not solve my problem.

Comment: Sadly this is impoissible because there can't be [duplicate function implementations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAIYD6ADmQE5mYBciAzlLYUQJTNgiYAjbLUQBvWrhC0kABgDcAXwCwAKFCRYCFOiy4CxctToNe-IbR6t2nMRKhSkAcgAS2ADZu4iAOpxab5EdFVSA). Basically, the overload function has to handle the type checking by itself :/

Comment: thank you @MikeS. ! So the second possibility is out, but how about the first approach with an if-conditional?

Comment: Granted you adjust the `if` conditions to actually check if the parameter is of that type, there shouldn't be any problems. You could use a custom typescript type guard to do that.